# How to use .get(id=some_model_field) in Model constraints?

Tags: python, django, model, constraints, metadata

I have class 'Car' class 'EngineType' and i want to add to it constraints. I want to check what type of engine is in the car, so i tried:

```
models.CheckConstraint(check=(Q(EngineType.objects.get(id=engine_type).name=='electric')), name='test_constraint')
```

where 'engine_type' is foreign key to EngineType.

It gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'engine_type' is not defined. Did you mean: 'EngineType'?
```

Constraints perfectly works without .get(), e.g.

```
models.CheckConstraint(check=(Q(engine_type=1)), name='test_constraint2'),
```

so it means that there is access to the 'engine_field' from constraints, but i have to check current engine type, not static.

Any help would appreciate!

'Car' and 'EngineType' listing without some other fields:

```
class EngineType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
class Car(models.Model):
    engine_type = models.ForeignKey(EngineType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(check=(Q(EngineType.objects.get(id=engine_type).name=='electric')), name='test_constraint')

    ]
```

Django automatically adds '*id* to foreign key fields, i tried to replace in .get() 'engine_type' to 'engine_type_id', but got the same error with 'engine_type' replaced to 'engine_type_id'.

Comment: What do you want to constraint exactly?

Comment: CHECK constraints are meant to check only the row being inserted/updated, not data in other tables. See Postgres docs for example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS ...PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table data other than the new or updated row being checked. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: models.CheckConstraint(check=(Q(EngineType.objects.get(id=engine_type.id).name=='electric')), name='test_constraint')

Comment: @user68369, спасибо огромное)
Да, это именно то, что мне и нужно было. То есть есть автомобиль, у него есть внешний ключ к таблице типов двигателей, мне нужно было проверить либо двигатель электрический, либо двигатель имеет рабочий объем от 0 до 30. Но так как у меня хранится не тип двигателя а внешний ключ, я не могу проверить engine_type='electric', а мне нужно по айди достать название мотора (electric) и сравнить его с 'electric', но пока печатал понял что есть вариант легче, проверил и он работает: Q(engine_type=EngineType.objects.get(name='Electric').id).
Еще раз огромное спасибо))

Comment: Jisson, doesen't work: same error. Above was explained why

Comment: @Alexander, i want to check if my engine is electic, or it has capacity > 0 and < 30. I can't check "engine_type='electric'", because engine_type - foreign key, so i tried to get the name by foreign key, but there is no success. Above was explained why

Comment: @DenisBilchenko Can you try this? models.CheckConstraint(check=(Q(F(engine_type__name)=='electric')), name='test_constraint')

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans same error "NameError: name 'engine_type__name' is not defined"
it seems like there's no way to put model fields in other objects/functions when CHECK
,the solution "Q(engine_type=EngineType.objects.get(name='Электрический').id)" works perfectly